# How can I parse xml attributes into a table using python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Hello I am attempting to parse some xml data into a table. I can get xml elements easily using the dom parser, but I am wondering the best way to access attributes and then put them in a data structure like a table.

```
<Module name="Filter_Module1">
    <register name="Control/Status_reg" offset="64">
        <field name="" offset="63" power_upval="0" access="R" isreset="cleared to 0">
            <description> Error:Received two Footer Packets with no corresponding Header or Data Packets.</description> 
        <field>

        <field name="" offset="62" power_upval="0" access="R" isreset="cleared to 0">
            <description> Received no footer packet after a data packet.  Can only be cleared by a reset</description> 
        <field>

        <field name="" offset="61" power_upval="0" access="R" isreset="cleared to 0">
            <description> Received no data packets between a header and a footer packet.  Can only be cleared by a reset.</description> 
        <field>

        <field name="" offset="60" power_upval="0" access="R" isreset="cleared to 0">
            <description> Error:Received two Footer Packets with no corresponding Header or Data Packets.</description> 
        <field>

    </register>
</Module>

<Module name="SRAM"></Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library provides support for parsing xml and executing XPATH queries

Comment: OK thank you, but how can I place these attributes in a table?